# Order of operations for quitting (also: how do counteroffers work?)

Tags: quitting

Getting ready to quit a job as a software engineer at a startup. I want to make sure that I'm doing everything in the correct order. This is what I am planning:

1. Accept the new job, to make sure we're confirmed, the offer wasn't a mistake, and they aren't going to renege (no promises, of course, at-will, etc.).
2. Once two weeks out, resign from my current job.
3. If applicable, decline any other job offers as their acceptance deadlines expire, not declining immediately after acceptance of the other offer to hedge against the offering company reneging.

Is this correct? Secondary question - I know not to accept a counteroffer (since I'll be marked as leaving already), but... how does that even work? If I've already accepted the other job before resigning, I can't exactly accept a counteroffer...

Comment: I recommend removing the counter offer side of things from the question as that's largely a separate topic. But they work much as you'd expect: either the employee wants a counter offer in which case he'll have the offer (and salary) but won't accept and doesn't intend to accept, or the employee would have to renege on his acceptance of the job offer.

Answer (score 7):

Order is:

1. Get new job offer in writing, clearly stating salary, benefits, start date etc.
2. Resign from current company and give them the 2 weeks notice
3. Done. Don't look back.

Comment: 1. Get new job offer in writing *without contingencies*.

Comment: @DanPichelman - agreed.

Comment: Also make sure you inform your new employer that you accept the offer. :P Further, depending on company policy and/or how your handlers react to the news, be prepared for your two weeks to possibly be cut short, even as much as being asked to leave the same day. Should that happen you can inform your new employer you're able to start early if you need/want to, or you can enjoy two weeks off until you start the new job. Your call.